# C - How to get a user defined function and turn it into a pointer?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I would like to know if there is any way of getting a user defined function (with two variables) from `stdin` in mathematical form and turn it into a function pointer. In other words, what I want to do is run:

```
> ./program a*b
```

Program turns that into a pointer of a function that returns:

```
 return a*b;
```

So, the output of `program` is

> user_defined_function(int)(int)

which would then be part of a much larger program.

I would post some code if I had any idea of how to tackle this problem, but I don't... I just need help with the step of turning the user defined function into a function pointer, since I know how to turn the user defined function into a C function.

Comment: Please, be more specific in what you try to achive. Do you want to generate code or something else? It's not clear to me in it's current form.

Comment: Mario the Spoon got what I meant, his answer explains it nicely. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple solution to that since you would have to generate code.

Simples solution that comes to my mind for this:

- generate a C file from within your programm that only has one function, inserting the command line argument as return statement
- give the function a known or generated name
- exec the compiler and generate a shared library
- dynamically load that shared library
- call the known function

I fear it doesn't get any simpler than that.

The other solution would be to write/ use an expression parser and parse the math expression and than evaluate at runtime...

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here is a link to [CINT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint)

> CINT is *an interpreter* for C and C++ code...
>
> ... A CINT script can call compiled classes/functions and **compiled code can make callbacks to CINT interpreted functions** ...

I'm not saying this is a "good" solution (and in fact it may be very "bad" in cases!), but some people have already put a good bit of effort -- "slightly less than 400,000 lines of code" -- into this project ;-)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

This is very hard to do in C because it is a compiled language.  You could do what **Mario The Spoon** is suggesting, or you could switch to a dynamic language like ruby or javascript.  These languages have an "eval" method that takes a string and executes the code inside the string, and they have the ability to dynamically define functions.

Comment: Yeqh, if the tools is not good enough change the tool! *like*

Answer (score 0):

What you're proposing is entirely possible, you simply write code which transforms user text into machine code. This is called a *compiler*. `gcc` would be much like your program, if it ran the code it generated.